# Missing modules in XD

Tags: spring-xd

I am trying to resolve very basic issue with Quick Start guide of Spring XD. But have already spent more than an hour.

I am following guide at http://projects.spring.io/spring-xd/#quick-start

But when I try create stream using following

```
**stream create --definition "time | log" --name ticktock --deploy**
```

It does not find standard module "log".

```
**Command failed org.springframework.xd.rest.client.impl.SpringXDException: Could not find module with name 'log' and type 'sink'**
```

I tried changing XD_HOME values to

```
/Users/sudhir/MyPrograms/spring-xd-1.2.0.RELEASE
/Users/sudhir/MyPrograms/spring-xd-1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-xd/xd
/Users/sudhir/MyPrograms/spring-xd-1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-xd
```

Tried to run xd-singlenode and xd-shell from XD_HOME using complete path.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in any case you should just be able to cd into
$INSTALLDIRECTORY/spring-xd-1.2.0.RELEASE/xd/bin and then run ./xd-singlenode.

> cd $INSTALLDIRECTORY/spring-xd-1.2.0.RELEASE/xd/bin
>
> ./xd-singlenode

Once you singlenode container is up and running start up xd-shell through $INSTALLDIRECTORY/spring-xd-1.2.0.RELEASE/shell/bin/xd-shell

> ./xd-shell

And you should at least be able to get tictoc up and running.  The ENV stuff is probably just your own environment.